# JAVA Bitwise XOR modulo

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, xor, modulo

I have to perform bitwise XOR on array of integers and then Return the answer modulo 998244353.
I have solved the first part but I have got stuck in 2nd part. I searched on the internet but couldn't find anything useful for this kind of combination of xor operator and modulo.
Please help.

Comment: You're making this too hard.  It is exactly the same as combining addition and division.  You just do the xors to produce an answer, then do `x % 998244353`.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the modulo operation on each iteration,

```
for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
{
    result = (result ^ arr[i])%998244353;
}
return result%998244353;
```

So that, it will reduce the number if the number is greater than 998244353.

Comment: `Return the answer modulo 998244353` doesn't mean you need to do modulo every iteration (which actually harms because it clears the upper bits) and then the next cycle the xor doesn't affect those bits anymore)